# Proper syntax for vlookup in open office

Tags: openoffice-calc

I'm using OpenOffice and I have two files, each with two columns.

[Serial Number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIqHx.png)

[Order Id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIrPV.png)

I want to add a third column in the Order ID table that contains the matching Serial Number based on the corresponding Order Name value.

I'm trying...

```
=VLOOKUP(A2;'orders_serials';!A2:B3130;2;0)
```

...in the column C of the Order Id file but I'm getting Err:510 "Variable is missing, for example when two operators are together "=1+*2"."

I certain I have a syntax problem but I can't identify it.

I've tried various edits, but I only get #NAME? or another Err:XXX.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the sheets in separate files (not just 2 sheets in the same file) you must reference the filename as well as the sheet name.  Have a look at https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Calc_Guide/Referencing_other_documents for OpenOffice official documentation on that.

Comment: They are in the same file now. Sheets named "orders" and "serials". In A2 of "orders" I have =VLOOKUP(A2;'serials';A2:B3130;2;0) b/c there are 3130 rows in serials. Getting #NAME?. Thoughts?

Comment: In testing (with a much smaller dataset) what has worked for me is:  =VLOOKUP(A2, serials.A1:B3130, 2, 0) .   I am running LibreOffice which was forked from OpenOffice so it should work the same.

Answer (score 0):

=VLOOKUP(A2;**'orders_serials'!A2:B3130**;2;0)
You may need to use commas depending on your language.